# sqlite database : get hourly count of items in col1 sorted by sum(col2)

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have a network of about 1000 sensors, pushing 48 bytes of data to my server, up to 4 times per day.
The server maintains an sqlite event database with following structure :

| timestamp | sensorid | operation | bytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 01:12:44 | ID1 | RX_DATA | 48 |
| 2021-04-01 01:15:23 | ID2 | RX_DATA | 0 (if error) |

I would like to follow up the daily progress of incoming data, displaying sensor count in each total data size buckets, resulting in a table like this :

| date time | 0 bytes | 48 bytes | 96 bytes | 144 bytes | 192bytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 01:00 | 3 | 30 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 02:00 | 4 | 50 | 20 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 03:00 | 2 | 30 | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 04:00 | 3 | 5 | 80 | 20 | 0 |
| 2021-04-01 05:00 | 1 | 2 | 100 | 50 | 8 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-04-02 00:00 | 2 | 1 | 76 | 630 | 145 |

So far I came up with following php script, which kind of works, but is very slow as database grows.
Sometimes leading to sqlite errors (locked db..)

Also, I would like to make it more generic, where data sizes would be figured out automatically.
And generating total per row would be great.

Obviously, I am lacking skills in sql queries. (not that my skills are much better on php :-))
But am pretty sure the php wrapping is not required and that sqlite alone  could generate the hourly times.

Thanks a lot for any hints and improvement suggestion.

```
 $entries_count = array(0, 48, 96, 144, 192);
 $start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));


for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    $end_time = $start_time + $i*60*60 ;
    printf("%-20s ;", date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $end_time));
    foreach ($entries_count as $cnt)
    {
        $query = "sqlite3 db/events.db " . "\"select COUNT(*) from (select sensor, SUM(bytes)  from events  where datetime(dt,'localtime')>'" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_time) ."' and datetime(dt,'localtime')<'" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $end_time) . "' group by sensor having SUM(bytes)=". $cnt .");\"" ;
        printf(" %10s ;", trim(shell_exec ($query)));
        //printf("%s\n", $query);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: *displaying sensor count in each total data size buckets* is not clear at all. In your query you `group by sensor` and getting the sum and then counting what? The sums? Post sample data that clarify what you want, better in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 Also, SQLite does have any pivot functionality, so *more generic* is not possible. You will have to do it with php code.

Comment: Running SQL queries in a loop (in your case even reconnecting in a nested loop) is usually a huge bottleneck. I'm not able to answer your question completely, but I'd recommend: 1) Connecting just once to the DB creating a resource and using this resource instead of the `shell_exec` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php) ... 2) Creating just 1 SQL query (or as few as possible) that returns all desired results and then looping over the results.

Comment: I am confused what your results are.  Are they cumulative throughout the day?  Or are they just what happens in each hour?

Comment: hello Gordon, results are cumulative throughout the day. The idea is to follow up the daily data retrieval process, and be able to say that, on a day x, at 12:00 that many sensors sent 48 bytes, or that we started to have sensors with full 192 bytes at 21:00. Hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following query would do what you want and all in a single execution :-

```
WITH  
    intermediate AS (SELECT 
    timestamp
        , CASE WHEN bytes <48 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r1 
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 48 AND bytes < 96 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r2
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 96 AND bytes < 144 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r3
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 144 AND bytes < 192 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r4
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 192 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r5
    FROM events  /* >>>>> INCLUDE YOUR WHERE CLAUSE HERE <<<<< */)
SELECT 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00',timestamp) AS 'date time'
    , sum(r1) AS '0Bytes'
    , sum(r2) AS '48Bytes'
    , sum(r3) AS '96Bytes'
    , sum(r4) AS '144Bytes'
    , sum(r5) AS '192Bytes'
FROM intermediate
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H',timestamp)
;
```

The WHERE clause hasn't been included but where it should go has been indicated.
You would simply amend the query to include the WHERE clause and then replace your existing query.
All the work is done by the query. You just extract the rows for the report.

**Explanation**

An intermediate CTE (Common Table Expression (basically a temporary table)) is created from the events table. This table contains columns :-

- timestamp copied exactly from the events table
- r1-r5 columns using the CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END construct to place either 0 or 1 into the column based upon the WHEN criteria

The CTE is then used as input to the final SELECT QUERY (you can have multiple CTE's and).

This final query groups according to the YYYY-MM-DD HH portion of the
timestamp, summing each of r1-r5 so counting the hits in the respective bytes range. The column names being changed to reflect the column names to be printed/output/displayed.

The YYYY-MM-DD HH followed by :00:00 is output as the date_time column (again as per the report).

WITH at the beginning is basically saying WITH the following CTE's do something (doesn't have to be  SELECT, could be UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT) see [The WITH clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

**Example**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (timestamp TEXT PRIMARY KEY, sensorid TEXT, operation TEXT, bytes INTEGER);
INSERT INTO events VALUES 
    ('2021-04-01 01:12:44','ID1','RX_DATA',48)
    ,('2021-04-01 01:12:54','ID2','RX_DATA',96)
    ,('2021-04-01 01:13:10','ID3','RX_DATA',0)
    ,('2021-04-01 01:12:15','ID4','RX_DATA',144)
    ,('2021-04-01 01:14:05','ID2','RX_DATA',192)
    ,('2021-04-01 01:13:25','ID5','RX_DATA',96)
    ,('2021-04-01 01:13:54','ID2','RX_DATA',48)
    ,('2021-04-01 01:14:54','ID2','RX_DATA',144)
    ,('2021-04-01 02:12:54','ID2','RX_DATA',96)
    ,('2021-04-01 03:12:54','ID2','RX_DATA',96)
    ,('2021-04-01 04:12:54','ID2','RX_DATA',96)
;

WITH  
    intermediate AS (SELECT 
    timestamp
        , CASE WHEN bytes <48 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r1 
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 48 AND bytes < 96 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r2
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 96 AND bytes < 144 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r3
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 144 AND bytes < 192 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r4
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 192 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r5
    FROM events  /* >>>>> INCLUDE YOUR WHERE CLAUSE HERE <<<<< */ )
SELECT 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00',timestamp) AS 'date time'
    , sum(r1) AS '0Bytes'
    , sum(r2) AS '48Bytes'
    , sum(r3) AS '96Bytes'
    , sum(r4) AS '144Bytes'
    , sum(r5) AS '192Bytes'
FROM intermediate
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H',timestamp)
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;
```

**Result**

[image]

> And generating total per row would be great.

The following will include totals (see comments for changes to the above)

```
WITH  
    intermediate AS (SELECT 
    timestamp
        , CASE WHEN bytes <48 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r1 
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 48 AND bytes < 96 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r2
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 96 AND bytes < 144 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r3
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 144 AND bytes < 192 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r4
        , CASE WHEN bytes >= 192 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r5
        , bytes /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
    FROM events  /* >>>>> INCLUDE YOUR WHERE CLAUSE HERE <<<<< */)
SELECT 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00',timestamp) AS 'date time'
    , sum(r1) AS '0Bytes'
    , sum(r2) AS '48Bytes'
    , sum(r3) AS '96Bytes'
    , sum(r4) AS '144Bytes'
    , sum(r5) AS '192Bytes'
    , sum(bytes) AS Total /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED */
FROM intermediate
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H',timestamp)
;
```

Result would then be :-

[image]

> Also, I would like to make it more generic, where data sizes would be figured out automatically.

This isn't at all specific. However you could easily programmatically build the SQL CASE clauses and the associated sum clauses and then build the entire query for execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot MikeT.  One point which I probably did not specify clearly : in the db, the bytes column contains either 0 (in case of communication error) or 48. Thus the need to sum up from start of day to be able to monitor progress .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, each row in the result set represents how many sensors are in each group.  If so, you want two levels of aggregation, one at the device/hour level and the other at the hour level.

The inner aggregate sums the total bytes for a sensor in a day.  The outer then just pivots this to get the counts in each group:

```
SELECT yyyymmddh,
       SUM(bytes_in_day = 0) as byes_0,
       SUM(bytes_in_day = 48) as byes_48,
       SUM(bytes_in_day = 96) as byes_96,
       SUM(bytes_in_day = 144) as byes_144,
       SUM(bytes_in_day = 192) as byes_192,
       SUM(bytes_in_day NOT IN (0, 48, 96, 144, 192)) as bytes_other
FROM (SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', timestamp) as yyyymmddhh,
             sensor,
             SUM(bytes) as bytes_in_hour,
             SUM(SUM(bytes)) OVER (PARTITION BY date(timestamp)) as bytes_in_day
      FROM events
      GROUP BY yyyymmddhh, sensor
     ) hs
GROUP BY yyyymmddhh;
```

If you want to filter by days, you can add a `WHERE` clause to the subquery.